# Installing Google Adwords Api Library (using docker)

Tags: api, docker, terminal, google-ads-api

Googles documentation on installing the library, found here: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/README.md#getting-started, instructs us to copy `adsapi_php.ini`, as constructed here: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/examples/AdWords/adsapi_php.ini, to your home directory.

I filled out the necessary variables in the .ini, and I am using docker so I have placed this file inside my container at /var/www/home/node/ and when I run the command `composer require googleads/googleads-php-lib` I am given the following error in the command prompt:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for googleads/googleads-php-lib ^37.1 -> satisfiable by googleads/googleads-php-lib[37.1.0].
    - googleads/googleads-php-lib 37.1.0 requires ext-soap * -> the requested PHP extension soap is missing from your system.

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
    - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/adsapi_php.ini
    - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pdo_pgsql.ini
    - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sodium.ini
    - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I assumed the issue was my adsapi_php.ini was simply in the wrong location as it contains what I believe is necessary to avoid the above issue, but I have tried placing it in several different places and yet I always get the same error.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to edit php.ini inside docker (docker exec -t {container} bashand enable there the extenstion soap